# UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection only Recognizes Right Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a left and right swipe gesture to every cell in my UITableView.  However, no one has seemed to answer this question no matter where I look.  Using this current solution, which is what is recommended, I do not enter the right gesture handler.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* right = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:right];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer* left = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:left];
```

I create two different Gesture recognizers for my solution.  However, I can never see a response from the right UIGestureRecognizer.  I don't understand why I never see a response from the right gesture recognizer only left one.

```
-(void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{ NSLog("You have swiped Left");
}
-(void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{ NSLog("You have swiped right"); //Never Enter this handler
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code...

I hope you don't mind its in swift.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            println("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            println("Swiped down")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see, but the only difference is having one handler, I have tried this, and it always gives the same UIGestureRecognizer.  So when I have one handler, the gesture recognizer is always left!!! Pulling out my hair now.  Any other ideas why I get same gesture everytime?